# Sigma additivity of events implies events being disjoint

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space and $(A_n)_n$ a sequence in $\mathcal{A}$.

If $\mathbb{P}(\bigcup_n A_n) = \sum\limits_{n} \mathbb{P}(A_n)$, then $\mathbb{P}(A_i \cap A_j) = 0$ for all $i,j \in \mathbb{N}, i \not= j$.

I have to prove that the $\sigma-$additivity of the probability measure implies that the events are pairwise disjoint.

It is clear that I could construct a disjoint sequence $B_n := A_n \setminus \bigcup_{k = 1}^{n-1} A_k$ that would satisfy the condition but that doesn't really help with this excercise.

Comment: Have you tried contradiction?

Comment: @Camille I'll try. Let's suppose that $\mathbb{P}(A_i \cap A_j) > 0$ for all $i,j \in \mathbb{N}, i \not= j$. Then obviously $A_i \cap A_j \not= \emptyset$. Therefore $\mathbb{P}(\bigcup_n A_n) < \sum_{n}\mathbb{P}(A_n)$, delivering the contradiction.

Comment: If you're looking for a brief answer that's alright I think, but your assumption for contradiction should read for *some* $i,j\in\mathbb{N},i\neq j$, not for all.

Comment: @Camille Surely, you're right. I just used copy/paste at the wrong place, "for all" negates into "exist".

Comment: Can you prove this for two sets?

Comment: @zhoraster Let $\mathbb{P}(A \cap B) > 0$. Using the inclusion-exclusion principle: $\mathbb{P}(A \cup B) = \mathbb{P}(A) + \mathbb{P}(B) - \mathbb{P}(A \cap B)$. Since $\mathbb{P}(A \cap B) > 0$, $\mathbb{P}(A \cup B) < \mathbb{P}(A) + \mathbb{P}(B)$

Comment: Very good! Now can you show that $P(\bigcup A_n)\le \sum_n P(A_n) - P(A_i\cap A_j)$ for *any* $i\neq j$?

Comment: @zhoraster It is: $\sum_n \mathbb{P}(A_n) - \mathbb{P}(A_i \cap A_j) = \sum_{n, i \not= n \not=j} \mathbb{P}(A_n) + \mathbb{P}(A_i) + \mathbb{P}(A_j) - \mathbb{P}(A_i \cap A_j) = \sum_{n, i \not= n \not=j} \mathbb{P}(A_n) + \mathbb{P}(A_i \cup A_j) \geq \mathbb{P}(\bigcup_{i \not= n \not= j} A_n) + \mathbb{P}(A_i \cup A_j) \geq \mathbb{P}(\bigcup_{i \not= n \not= j} A_n \cup (A_i \cup A_j)) = \mathbb{P}(\bigcup_n A_n)$.

Comment: Correct! Note that the inequality is strict iff $P(A_i\cap A_j) >0$. Are you able to conclude?

Comment: @zhoraster Yes, thank you for the more formal proof since my first draft was lacking the real arguments here and there. So the result would be: Assuming $P(A_i \cap A_j) > 0$ for any $i,j \in \mathbb{N}, i \not= j$, it can be concluded, using the already proved inequality, that: $P(\bigcup_n A_n) < \sum_n P(A_n)$.

Comment: Not "for any", but "for some"! But otherwise it is true.

Answer (score 1):

Define $f:=\sum_n \mathbf 1_{A_n}-\mathbf 1_{\bigcup_n A_n}$. This function is non-negative  and its integral is zero, so $f=0$ almost surely. Therefore, the function $\sum_n \mathbf 1_{A_n}$ can take only the values $0$ and $1$.